# How to handle Server not responding Exception in asp.net mvc?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, server-error

How do i simulate and handle the server not responding error? And which case do u think it might occur, as when u request a page from the server and if its not responding wouldnt it throw page cant be displayed error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server not responding would be a client-level error, which will be shown to you by the browser. You can't handle it because due to the server not responding the control has not been given to your application yet.

Unless you're talking about the database not responding to an application request. In which case an exception will be thrown which you could intercept by using the [HandleError] attribute or writing your own for that task.